# ServiceBusNamespace is invalid at deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

Im trying to deploy a ServiceBus through an ARM template. I ive tried all these versions as the serviceBusNamespaceName value with the same error message:

Not working (using resource group named: 'INT001-TestOrderStore-Cert' ) :

- "[concat('INT1001-ServiceBus-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
- "[concat('INT1001-ServiceBus', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
- "[concat('INT1001-MyOwnName', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
- "[concat('int1001-myownname', uniqueString(toLower(resourceGroup().id))]"

but always get the same error message:

> 2020-03-22T11:54:07.2612863Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "The specified service namespace is invalid. CorrelationId: 43105e81-4248-41d6-ba91-9070e8ac4637",
>       "code": "BadRequest"
>     }
>   }

This is the only one that has worked so far: 
"sbnslau-1fa155e2-b3fb-48b9-a204-af1d2a02f40c"

So i need to understand what is going wrong when i try to use concat and unique string. Is there anyway in the azure portal i can evaluate the expression to se what it resolves too?

This is what my ARM looks like:

sbArmDeploy.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

SbArmDeploy-Parameters.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "value": "sbns_1fa155e2-b3fb-48b9-a204-af1d2a02f40c"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I try to create a Service Bus Namespace using the name you provided (`sbns_1fa155e2-b3fb-48b9-a204-af1d2a02f40c`) in Azure Portal, I got the following error:

> The namespace can contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens. The
>   namespace must start with a letter, and it must end with a letter or
>   number

Basically the issue is that you have an underscore (_) in the namespace name which is not allowed. Please remove that or change that to a hyphen (-) and you will not get the error.

You can find the naming rules for a Service Bus Namespace here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/create-namespace.

---

As discussed in the comments, the problem is coming because you're defining a variable in parameters file. What you would need to do is define them in variables section in your main template file.

For example, here're the ArmDeploy.json and Parameters.json files I used:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "serviceBusNamespaceName": "[concat('INT1001-ServiceBus-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "name": "[variables('serviceBusNamespaceName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard",
                "tier": "Standard"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

---

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "value": "eastus"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im so sorry. I forgot to add all the different ns ive tried. Several without hyphen! Please have  a look at op again. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Is there anyway you can check what's the value for the Namespace name that is being sent over the wire? I just tried with `INT1001-ServiceBus-odihjdpknkbet` (last part is the output of `uniqueString` function based on your resource group name) and I don't get any name validation errors.

Comment: I dont know! That would be very helpfull. Do you know how i can check it? I know that the ResourceGroup name is what i put in OP. But i dont know how to evaluate the expression to see what it resolves to. And the error log gives no such information either.

Comment: I believe the issue is that most likely you're defining `"[concat('INT1001-ServiceBus-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"` in your parameters.json file. I tried the same and got the same error. I think you would need to define this under `variables` in your sbArmDeploy.json file.

Comment: Oh so its not possible to use these helper functions in the parameter file?

Comment: I think so. Let me deploy one template and confirm.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I defined it in variables section and the deployment was successful.

Comment: Updated my answer with templates I used. HTH.